# How to deselect using :not according to css property and value

Tags: css

i want to select all **div** but not which has position:absolute;
how to select like this?

```
<div style="position:relative;">
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;">
</div>

<div style="position:relative;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no CSS selector that checks the value of certain properties. However, assuming the inline style doesn't change, `div[style*='relative']` may work for you.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2Ewu/